# Image Loading onto Jquery ui-grid element

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

```
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-h" style="height:120px;text-align:center;font-size:12px"><img src="pic1.jpeg"><p align="center">P1</p></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-h" style="height:120px;text-align:center;font-size:12px"><img src="pic2.jpeg"><p align="center">P2</p></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-h" style="height:120px;text-align:center;font-size:12px"><img src="pic3.jpeg"><p align="center">P3</p></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-h" style="height:120px;text-align:center;font-size:12px"><img src="pic4.jpeg"><p align="center">P4</p></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-h" style="height:120px;text-align:center;font-size:12px"><img src="pic5.jpeg"><p align="center">P5</p></div></div>
  </div>
```

I am parsing a JSON Web service, and I want to extract the number of elements from the response and show the images. (in the above case 5 images, and this has to be dynamic based on the number of elements in the JSON.

JSON Web Service: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?

I am extracting items.title and items.media.m to replace P1 and pic1.jpeg using $.each() jquery syntax.

How to dynamically generate the number of div elements when there are 3 classes, like ui-block-a, ui-block-b and ui-block-c alternatively. Is there a better way of doing this ?

Is using tables a better solution here rather than jquery ui-grid ?

Comment: can u show us some more code pls? :) like ur JS?

Comment: There is an example here, which Loads the four most recent pictures of Mount Rainier from the Flickr JSONP API. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/   I want to use ui-grid-b such that only 3 images show up on each row.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005298/looping-inside-a-while-loop-mysqli-fetch-array